# Largest values in 32-bitIEEE floating point

Tags: floating-point, integer

Let's say we have S as the set of all 32-bit IEEE floating-point values that are integers.

-How many integers are in S?

Would it be 2^32? Since there are 32 bytes and 2 options, 0 and 1.

-What’s the largest odd value of S?

How can I calculate this?

-What are the largest two values of S?

-How many consecutive integers are in S?

Is this a combinatorics questions? If so, how can I approach this?

-The number 232 is in S. What are its nearest neighbours? In other words, what two values in S are closest to 232?

Comment: Definitely not 2^32. Is this an interview question, or a homework?

Comment: Just a hint to let you think yourself: A floating point (FP) value is represented by mantisa and exponent. Because of this: (1.) Large FP values are always integers, and (2.) all small integers are present in set S.

Comment: Just think about it: not every value a 32 bit float represents is an integer, so it ***cannot*** represent 2^32 integers.